# subfields in firestore with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, nested

I am working on a flutter app for football league. I have created a database in firestore with subfileds. I am facing trouble in accessing the subfields. Can someone please help me with the code. I want a code to pass the values or an object through constructor.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"